# How to set system ringtone of device as local notification sound?

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification

I want to set the system ringtones of device as local notification sound from my app. I get the list of system ringtones present in my device but not able to set it for notification as the ringtone path is not accessible in the application bundle. Is there any way to get the access and able to set it as notification sound

Comment: you just need to set the souname property. search the name of your ringtone and set it

Comment: I tried that way, but its not working. It sets to default. 
Path of the system ringtone is like this: /System/Library/Audio/UISounds/Tink.caf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After lots of research I could solve my problem, I just had to copy the System/Sounds to the Library/Sounds/notification.caf
Like this:

```
NSFileManager* fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSArray *libraryDir = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *lib = [libraryDir objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *directoryPath = [lib stringByAppendingString:@"/Sounds"];
@try {
    [fileManager createDirectoryAtPath:directoryPath withIntermediateDirectories:TRUE attributes:nil error:nil];
    NSString *systemSoundPath = fromPath; // eg. /System/Library/Audio/UISounds/Tink.caf
    NSString *notificationSoundPath = [directoryPath stringByAppendingString:@"/notification.caf"];
    BOOL fileExist = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath: notificationSoundPath];
    if(fileExist){
        [fileManager removeItemAtPath:notificationSoundPath error:nil];
    }
    [fileManager copyItemAtPath:systemSoundPath toPath:notificationSoundPath error:nil];

} @catch (NSException *exception) {
    NSLog(@"in catch");
} @finally {
    NSLog(@"in catch");
}
```

Please check, if its helpful to anyone else.

Comment: Hi Dheeraj Gupta. I am successfully make hard copy of sound in Sounds/notification.caf. 
I also assign whole path of  notification.caf as UIlocalnotification,soundnamebut for me not working